# Choosing schema in the slave host replication set Usin Slony-I

Tags: postgresql, slony

I am using slony-I to replicate tables from one server to another. I have to databases on the master slave that have same exact tables , and i want to replicate them to a single table in the slave. I can create the same tables in different schemas in the slave table , however i cant determine the schema in the replication set in the slave host.

I want to be able to determine the schema i am replicating to on the slave host.

How can i do this in slony?

Thank you

Comment: did you have any luck i'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @Charif Hello , Unfortunetly you can't choose the schema on the slave host.The schema name and table name should be identical on both the master and slave. A Work around for this thing is to create another schema on both databases on slave and master and use them in ur slony replication

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't choose the schema on the slave host in slony.The schema name and table name should be identical on both the master and slave. A Work around for this thing is to create another schema on both databases on slave and master and use them in your slony replication

Comment: i think i'm going to create 100 database on my server or use DFW to consolidate my data